# content_scripts.matches is invalid for Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

For some reason I'm getting an error:

[image: Chrome extension error]

With the following manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Genie Extension",
  "description": "An extension to put genie's lamp in every website you visit.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": "<all_urls>",
      "js": [
        "genie.js",
        "uxGenie.js",
        "angular.js",
        "jquery.js",
        "extension.js"
      ],
      "css": ["styles.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Based on [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html), I was under the impression that I could use the `<all_urls>` match... But it looks like that's not true? What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I tried other patterns and it looks like they're all not working. Is there something else wrong with the way I'm doing things here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `"matches": "<all_urls>"` to `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]` and it should work.

Comment: Just barely figured this out. Wow... Come on Google! Haha. Thanks!